# Firestore transaction, max documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

It will come at some point that perhaps I will have to update more than 500 documents, but first I have to read and update all the data to be fine. How would you do this with transactions?

I did something similar with `_.chunk` with batch. But this time I need a transaction but I wouldn't know how to do.

transaction:

```
    if (previousValue.Name !== newValue.Name || previousValue.Image !== newValue.Image) {

        const chatRoomQuery = db.collection(chatsCollection).where(userIdsProperty, 'array-contains', userId);

        const transactions = _.chunk(chatRoomQuery, maxSize) => {
                return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
                    return transaction.getAll(chatRoomQuery).then(docs => {
                        docs.forEach(doc => {
                            let chatRoom = doc.data();

                            let oldUser = {
                                Id: previousValue.Id,
                                Name: previousValue.Name,
                                Image: previousValue.Image
                            };

                            let newUser = {
                                Id: newValue.Id,
                                Name: newValue.Name,
                                Image: newValue.Image
                            };

                            let index = chatRoom.Users.indexOf(oldUser);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                chatRoom.Users.splice(index, 1, newUser);
                                transaction.update(doc.ref, chatRoom)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
            });

        await Promise.all(transactions);
    }
```

I think I have a syntax error not getting it right.
I leave a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It is hard to help better with "I don't know" than the documentation does: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#web If you are stuck when using transactions, show us what you've already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: the code that I put above I have to pass it to a transaction

Comment: Sounds feasible. What's keeping you from doing that yourself based on the documentation I linked?

Comment: edit my question with the code I am testing

Comment: Thanks for that. What is the problem with that new code fragment?

Comment: there is an error: TS1005: ';'    const transactions = _.chunk(chatRoomQuery, maxSize) => {

Comment: Please make sure the entire error message is in the question. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to tell us what the exact problems is in your code.

Comment: I re-edited the question and attached a screenshot

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense indeed. I think you may be looking for `_.chunk(chatRoomQuery, maxSize).forEach((transaction) => {` instead of  `_.chunk(chatRoomQuery, maxSize) => {`. But I'm not sure, as I don't see where you're using the chunks in the code.

Comment: I don't understand this very well: since I don't see where you are using the snippets in the code.

And how could you update (maybe) more than 500 documents in one transaction to keep it consistent? because I need to read the array and update an element of that array and keep all the same

Comment: In this case, I believe that the solution from frank will iterate over all the transactions as it is surrounded with a forEach statement. Is this what you meant?